# nodejs app doesn't receive SIGTERM when running in AppEngine Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a nodejs app running in the AppEngine Standard Environment. I'm expecting to receive `SIGTERM` from the environment during deployments or when autoscaling so that I can start a "graceful shutdown" process. My `process.on('SIGTERM', handler)` handler is not being called.

Should I be getting `SIGTERM` like I'm expecting or are my expectations wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App engine standard environment only destroys and create instances, without send any signal before scale up or scale down.

Keep in mind that App Engine STD runs over a [sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#when-to-choose-the-standard-environment) runtime and has lack of some OS perks.

If you need run some tasks on shutdown application time is recommended to use App Engine Flexible Environment, this environment can [handle `SIGTERM` signals](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#application_shutdown)